# Contact Form 7 doesn't call ajax

Tags: contacts, contact-form-7

Contact Form 7 doesn't call ajax on my translated site. Ajax works perfecly on my default language site.

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show us what you already tried

Comment: Submitting the form in the secondary language fails. This producess the below console error:
xxxxx/wp-json?lang=it/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/XXX/feedback 404 (Not Found)